# NGINX URI rewrite/add pattern

Tags: nginx

Having the uri `/test/test.ssm/.umm/view=500-974652006`, I need to have NGINX this converted to:

`/test/test_new.ssm/.umm/view=500-974652006`. In other words, add the `_new` pattern when capturing the .ssm URI.
I have tried the following NGINX configurations, but nothing worked:

`rewrite ^(.*).ssm.*)$   $1_new.ssm$2;`

`location / { set $proxyurl 'http://backend'; if ($request_uri ~* "(.*).ssm(.*)") { set $proxyurl 'http://backend/$1_new.ssm$2'; }     proxy_pass $proxyurl; }`

thank you.

Comment: An `if` block inside a `location` block [will not work](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). You could use a `rewrite...break` statement within the `location` block. For example, try: `rewrite ^(.*)\.ssm(.*)$ $1_new.ssm$2 break;`

Comment: I tried the rewrite `^(.*)\.ssm(.*)$ $1_new.ssm$2 break;` but it didn't work.